# How can I undo OCR in Foxit?

Tags: ocr, foxit-reader, undo

Optical character recognition (OCR) in Foxit sometimes mess up the font. E.g., before OCR:

[image]

After OCR:

[image]

How can I undo OCR in Foxit? Ctrl+Z doesn't undo OCR. I use Foxit 11.2 on Windows 10. I made some unsaved changes to the PDF prior to OCR.

Comment: Any answers or comments are welcome.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.